# Expected size of the min-cut, under edge perturbations

Tags: pr.probability, randomized-algorithms, random-graphs

Suppose we have a graph $G(V, E)$. 
Assume that the min-cut of this graph is given $C=(A/B)$ and denote the size of the cut with $|C|$.

Create a random modification of the graph:

- Drop each existing edge with probability $\alpha$.
- Add edges between the node-pairs that don't already have an edge with probability $\beta$.

Is it possible to say something about the expected size of the min-cut in the modified graph? (possibly under some extra assumptions)

Comment: was thinking that moving to the "math" forum might be a better place for this ...

Comment: Consider your two modification steps separately.  The effect of the first one will depend highly on the structure of the graph.  E.g. consider G1 consisting of a path of length n (with min cut 1) vs. G2 consisting of two n/2-cliques connected by a single edge (also having min cut 1).  Dropping each edge with probability some small $\alpha>0$ will disconnect G1 with probability about $1-(1-\alpha)^n \approx \alpha n$.  In contrast it will disconnect G2 with probability about $\alpha$.

Comment: As for the second step, the min cut in the resulting graph is, up to a factor of two, the maximum of two quantities: (i) the min cut in the graph after step 1, and (ii) the min cut in the random graph that has each possible edge with probability $\beta$.  The latter quantity is probably well-studied.